# ActiveAdmin/Httparty: Can I access json response from variable in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activeadmin, httparty

I'm using an ActiveAdmin custom page and httparty to request a json response from a third-party api. I've successfully accessed the json data response, parsed it, set it to a variable, and used puts to see it in my console.

How can I access this variable to view it on an activeadmin page?

Here's my activeadmin page:

```
  ActiveAdmin.register_page "API" do
    content do
        response = HTTParty.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=war&apikey=#####")
        res = response.body
        result = JSON.parse res
        @title = result["Search"][0]["Title"]
        puts @title
    end

    controller do
        # response = HTTParty.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=war&apikey=#####")
        # res = response.body
        # result = JSON.parse res
        # @title = result ["Search"][0]["Title"]
        # puts @title
    end
  end
```

What I've tried:

- *capturing JSON data from api works in either the content or controller block.
- using a partial to render embedded ruby: <%= @title %>
- capturing json data in controller and display @title in content area

Comment: Addition: I used the following to render the partial - render 'admin/index'

Answer (score 0):

`text_node` instead of `puts` should work here, see https://activeadmin.info/12-arbre-components.html